# IBM Web MQ printing exceptions differently on different systems

Tags: exception, websphere, ibm-mq

I have the same piece of software running on several machines, but the way that errors are reported are inconsistent.

All the software is doing is printing out the exception thrown when (for example) trying to connect to a Message Queue.

Some machines report the error with the text description

> MQRC_DATA_LENGTH_ERROR ---> IBM.WMQ.MQException: MQRC_DATA_LENGTH_ERROR

Others just report the error code.

> 2538 ---> IBM.WMQ.MQException: 2538

I'm not sure why this is, but I believe it is related to the amqmdnet DLL being updated from v8 to v9. It seems to have been correctly configured on all systems, and I can't find any v8 DLLs in use. Is there something I'm missing? Somewhere else I should look? Something else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was that IBM MQ was installed on the machines that were reporting errors with text descriptions, and not on the others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there could be changes in the 'message text' of an MQException between MQ V8 and V9.

You don't show your code but are you just dumping out the exception?

i.e.

```
catch (MQException e)
{
   System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
}
```

The correct way to handle an MQ exception is as follows:

```
catch (MQException e)
{
   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQException CC=" + e.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + e.ReasonCode);
}
```